# Nginx configuration for Node JS in Windows 10

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, nginx

I am building an application using *Node JS*, and *Angular JS* in *Windows 10*.
I want to integrate *Nginx* with it. I am new to it. I have read several articles on it but get confused how to configure it.

I have run the app in `localhost:3000/` i.e. *Express* default port. Should I on the *Node JS* server using `nodemon server.js`?

Some of the lines of my configuration of *Nginx* like below,

**file**: `C:\nginx-1.13.0\conf\nginx.conf`

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root C:/Users/asau/Documents/archlb/src/public;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            #root   html;
            # C:/Users/asau/Documents/archlb/src/public;
            # index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /images/ {

        }

        location /js/ {
           # root C:/Users/asau/Documents/archlb/src/public/js
        }
```

When I use `localhost` the `index.html` opens in the browser but it can't access the REST APIs which are calling from Angular JS. All Angular JS files are included in `index.html`. And it shows `can not get localhost/getversion (404)` error in Google Chrome Developer tools.

But, if I use `localhost:3000/` everything works fine.
What configuration should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need at least, on `proxy_pass` rule to your API. Something like

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000
}
```

Some pointers to documentation :

- https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: thanks for your help. It works!!